# jQuery Table Row Mouseover issue

Tags: jquery, html-table, mouseover, tablerow

I have the following code:

```
$('table tr:not(:first)').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('hovered_error');
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
  }).mouseout(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

The above works a treat in ensuring that the first row of a table is excluded from the 'mouseover'and 'mouseout' functions.

However, the issue is I have multiple tables on the page and whilst the first table row is ignored the rest aren't.

I'm not sure how to adapt the above to account for multiple tables - is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$('table tr:not(:first-child)').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aCLvU/)